# Missing ADUC tabs after RSAT install Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, active-directory, mmc

After a fresh installation of Windows 10.0.10240, I installed RSAT 1.2. All the tools are there, but when opening ADUC the only tab I have is COM+. I'm running the MMC under an account with domain admin access, I've reinstaled RSAT several times, disabled the AD DS tools and re-enabled them, made sure .Net3.5 is working in case this is one of those things, ran dsa.msc directly and by adding it into a blank MMC console, and still nothing.

I can run ADAC in the same user context and have full domain admin rights and can do everything I need to, but ADAC kinda sucks compared to the old MMC. PowerShell AD cmdlets also all work.

I'm assuming this is a result of some .dll failing to register somewhere, but I have no idea what .dll I'm going to need to re-register to fix.

What I'm getting from my new desktop:

[image: ADUC User properties]

What I get on my old desktop, and when logging into a DC:
[image: ADUC User Properties like they should be]

RSAT installation status:

[image: RSAT Installation Options]

Comment: Which version/build of Windows 10 are you using?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 10 Enterprise 2015 LTSB - 10.0.10240

Comment: Did you install this version: https://www.microsoft.com/en-sa/download/details.aspx?id=45520

Comment: @uSlackr yeah, that's the one I installed.

Comment: According to this PFE post: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askpfeplat/2017/01/03/remote-server-administration-tools-for-windows-10/ 
you need Windows 10 build 1607 to run this version of RSAT as it is tied to Windows Server 2016 release.  The article describes the issue you were seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some weird issue with language packs and the way they're installed that breaks the installation of RSAT 1.2 on a fresh install of Windows 10, 10240 and other builds according to several forum posts. Upgrade installations (7/8/8.1-10) don't seem to be impacted by this issue.

I was able to fix this issue by uninstalling kb2693643, rebooting and reinstalling using an older version of RSAT. The file has been shared by someone on [Spiceworks](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1183656-missing-tabs-in-aduc-on-windows-10) and [Technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/99437fe2-1d6f-44e2-9654-5fd74b486c7b/rsat-windows-10-aduc-missing-normal-tabs?forum=win10itproapps&prof=required).

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue by switching to Windows 10 , 1607 version. And everything works fine , you need not delete any KB .

Comment: Migrating away from a stable branch to one that changes configuration and installed applications over time is not a viable solution.

Comment: @RobbieCrash yes i have checked the solution also provided by you , but due to security concern using an install from someone off the web is not allowed in our work environment. thanks for your valuable input tho. Happy Holidays !